# Writing result set to csv

Tags: java, resultset

I am trying to write the resultset to a csv file using the following code,

```
public static String getstaffid(String var_1, Connection connection,
        FileWriter fw) throws SQLException, Exception
// Create a statement
{
    String record = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    boolean empty = true;
    try {
        rs = stmt
                .executeQuery("select username, firstname, lastname, middlename, street, city, stateorprovince, ziporpostalcode, countryorregion, fax, phone, extension, mobile, pager, title, primaryemail, secondaryemail, officename, description, comments, suspendeddate, userdata, employeeid, createuser, updateuser, createdate, updatedate, employeetype, servicedeskticketnumber, startdate, enddate, manager, businessapprover, technicalapprover, delegate, location, jobcodes, customproperty1, customproperty2, customproperty3, customproperty4, customproperty5, customproperty6, customproperty7, customproperty8, customproperty9, customproperty10 from globalusers where username = '"+ var_1 + "'");
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();


            while (rs.next()) {
            empty = false;
            record = rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(5) + " " + rs.getString(6) + " " + rs.getString(7) + " " + rs.getString(8) + " " + rs.getString(9) + " " + rs.getString(10) + " " + rs.getString(11) + " " + rs.getString(12) + " " + rs.getString(13) + " " + rs.getString(14) + " " + rs.getString(15) + " " + rs.getString(16) + " " + rs.getString(17) + " " + rs.getString(18) + " " + rs.getString(19) + " " + rs.getString(20) + " " + rs.getString(21) + " " + rs.getString(22) + " " + rs.getString(23) + " " + rs.getString(24) + " " + rs.getString(25) + " " + rs.getString(26) + " " + rs.getString(27) + " " + rs.getString(28) + " " + rs.getString(29) + " " + rs.getString(30) + " " + rs.getString(31) + " " + rs.getString(32) + " " + rs.getString(33) + " " + rs.getString(34) + " " + rs.getString(35) + " " + rs.getString(36) + " " + rs.getString(37) + " " + rs.getString(38) + " " + rs.getString(39) + " " + rs.getString(40) + " " + rs.getString(41) + " " + rs.getString(42) + " " + rs.getString(43) + " " + rs.getString(44) + " " + rs.getString(45) + " " + rs.getString(46) + " " + rs.getString(47);
            fw.append(rs.getString(1));
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append(rs.getString(2));
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append(rs.getString(3));
            fw.append('\n'); 
            }
            System.out.println(record);
        }
         finally {
        fw.flush();
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }

    return record;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. But to retrieve a string record, i had to write something like
record = rs.getString(1) + " " +........+ " " + rs.getString(47). If for like say tomorrow if the query request for more attributes i have to add more rs.getString(48) and so on.

So i wrote a function like the below,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                 record = rs.getString(i) + " ";
                  }
```

where the value of columns,

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
```

But now i just get

null
null
.
.
.
null.

Also instead of appending fw.append(rs.getString(1)).....fw.append(rs.getSting(n)), is there a small function i can write to avoid adding more of these append.

Many Thanks

Comment: Instead of writing it yourself, use OpenCSV

Comment: This is a prod environment, i can only use standard jdk 1.6 and cannot export any third party library to accomplish this.

Comment: @navman are you writing the for loop outside the while loop?

Comment: No.. The forloop is within the while loop.

Comment: @navman show the full code(for within while)

Comment: Hi, I couldnt copy the entire code here, Its the same as above list. Just that i commented out record in while loop from above code and replaced it with for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
               record = rs.getString(i) + " ";
                }

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Thanks. For someone who could get used with it, am attaching the code

```
public static String getstaffid(String var_1, Connection connection,
        FileWriter fw) throws SQLException, Exception
// Create a statement
{
    String record = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    boolean empty = true;
    try {
            rs = stmt
                .executeQuery("select username, firstname, lastname, middlename, street, city, stateorprovince, ziporpostalcode, countryorregion, fax, phone, extension, mobile, pager, title, primaryemail, secondaryemail, officename, description, comments, suspendeddate, userdata, employeeid, createuser, updateuser, createdate, updatedate, employeetype, servicedeskticketnumber, startdate, enddate, manager, businessapprover, technicalapprover, delegate, location, jobcodes, customproperty1, customproperty2, customproperty3, customproperty4, customproperty5, customproperty6, customproperty7, customproperty8, customproperty9, customproperty10 from globalusers where username = '"+ var_1 + "'");
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();


            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                empty = false;
                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) 
                {
                 record = rs.getString(i);
                 fw.append(rs.getString(i));
                 fw.append(',');
                }
                fw.append('\n');

            }
        }
        finally 
        {
            fw.flush();
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }

    return record;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a query

```
 "SELECT id,text,price into OUTFILE  '"+your-filename+
                    "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM testtable t"
```